# pyspark remove duplicate rows based on column value

Tags: python, pyspark, duplicates, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have an **PySpark RDD**. I want to **eliminate duplicates** *only when "column 1" and "column 2" matches in the next row*. This is how the data looks like:

```
2,10482422,0.18
2,10482422,0.4
2,10482423,0.15
2,10482423,0.43
2,10482424,0.18
2,10482424,0.49
2,10482425,0.21
2,10482425,0.52
2,10482426,0.27
2,10482426,0.64
2,10482427,0.73
```

In the above example, I just want one maximum value of column three for each row by deleting other duplicate rows

Expected output is:

```
2,10482422,0.4
2,10482423,0.43
2,10482424,0.49
2,10482425,0.52
2,10482426,0.64
2,10482427,0.73
```

I tried creating a dataframe and using `df.dropDuplicates()` but it doesn't give the expected answer. How can I keep the maximum value in this RDD based on two columns?

This is a 350 GB RDD, any optimal suggestions will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think reduceByKey will help here.

Remember that when using reduceByKey or any other "By Key" transformation or action you can define the key to be a tuple.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(2,10482422,0.18),
(2,10482422,0.4),
(2,10482423,0.15),
(2,10482423,0.43),
(2,10482424,0.18),
(2,10482424,0.49),
(2,10482425,0.21),
(2,10482425,0.52),
(2,10482426,0.27),
(2,10482426,0.64),
(2,10482427,0.73)])

print rdd.map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1]), x[2]))\
.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x if x >= y else y)\
.collect()
```

result:

```
[((2, 10482427), 0.73),
 ((2, 10482425), 0.52),
 ((2, 10482426), 0.64),
 ((2, 10482423), 0.43),
 ((2, 10482424), 0.49),
 ((2, 10482422), 0.4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% clear from your answer whether you want to use DataFrames or not, but if you are happy to create a DF from your RDD then you could also use the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.groupby('column1', 'column2')
  .agg(f.max(f.col('value').alias('maxval'))
```